# How to write $\pi_1$

Tags: symbols

I am writing an article and I need to write the fundamental group. For that we use `$\pi_1\left(X,x_0\right)$`. 
However I am arriving at the following error:

```
Use of \pi doesn't match its definition.
l.113 This shall be denoted by $ \pi_
                                     {1}(X,x_0)$ or simply $ \pi_1\left(X\right)$.
```

My Code is given below.

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

%-------Packages---------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,arc]{xy}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@thm
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator\pione{\pi_1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pi1et}{\pi^{\'et}_1}

\newcommand {\sub}{\mbox{SB}}

\begin{document}

Given a "nice" topological space $\left(X, x_0\right)$, we define the fundamental group to be $\left[S^1, (X, x_0)\right]_{\star}$. 
This shall be denoted by $ \pi_{1}(X,x_0)$ or simply $ \left(X\right)$.  

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  unfortunately, the brief snippet of code that you provide isn't enough to diagnose the problem.  (other than the fact that `\left` and `\right` aren't needed, the math expression looks to be input correctly.  all i can think of is that somehow, `\pi` has been redefined from its basic meaning.  please provide a small compilable example (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that results in the error you have quoted.  then people here will have the information they need to experiment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers are not allowed in macro names in LaTeX:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\pi1et}{\pi^{\'et}_1}
```

This defines macro `\pi` that expects the parameter text `1et`.
Use a name like `\pioneet` to follow the naming scheme of the
previous operator:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\pioneet}{...}
```

BTW, `\'` is a text mode command that is invalid in math mode.
Either use text if `ét` is used as word:

```
\pi^{\text{\'et}}
```

or math, if the accent has mathematical meaning:

```
\pi^{\acute{e}t}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are looking for something like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

For that we use $\pi _1(X,x_0)$.

For that we use ${\pi}_1(X,x_0)$.

For that we use $\pi{}_1(X,x_0)$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message shows that TeX has successfully parsed `\pi` as command name. The problem is the definition `\DeclareMathOperator{\pi1et}{...}`. `1et` is now a mandatory parameter text and TeX expects `1` as next token after `\pi`.

Comment: Now, with the added example of the problem, your solution is obvious.